# A condition from switch is not read

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a calendar but It couldn't read my leap year. When the output is displayed month 2 doesn't show 29 days.

```js
for (var year = 2010 ; year <= 2019 ; year++){
    for (var month = 1 ; month <=12 ; month++){
        var dateLength;
        switch(true){
            case (month === 1 ||month === 3 ||month === 5 || month ===7|| month ===8||month ===10 || month ===12 ):
                dateLength = 31;
                break;
            case (month === 2 && month%4 ===0):
                dateLength = 29;
                break;
            case (month === 2 && month%4 !==0 ):
                dateLength = 28;
                break;
            default: 
                dateLength = 30;
        }
        for (var day = 1 ; day <= dateLength; day ++){
            console.log(day,"/",month,"/",year)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check `year` for leap year not the `month`

Comment: And be careful with code like this... not every year divisible by 4 is a leap year.

Comment: lol .. thank you so much

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year

Comment: Also, as a general code pattern, a loop, that contains a loop, that contains a loop is rarely (if ever) necessary or a good coding practice.

Comment: You're checking month instead of year for leap year

Answer (score 1):

You're checking month instead of year:

```
case (month === 2 && month%4 ===0):
```

should be

```
case (month === 2 && year%4 ===0):
```

Then your final code will be looks like

```js
for (var year = 2010 ; year <= 2019 ; year++){
    for (var month = 1 ; month <=12 ; month++){
        var dateLength;
        switch(true){
            case (month === 1 ||month === 3 ||month === 5 || month ===7|| month ===8||month ===10 || month ===12 ):
                dateLength = 31;
                break;
            case (month === 2 && year%4 ===0):
                dateLength = 29;
                break;
            case (month === 2 && year%4 !==0 ):
                dateLength = 28;
                break;
            default: 
                dateLength = 30;
        }
        for (var day = 1 ; day <= dateLength; day ++){
            console.log(day,"/",month,"/",year)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start.
No need to do your own calculations

```js
const aDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const months = "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec".split(",");

function writeMonth(year, month, startDay, endDay) {
  document.write("<hr/>" + year + "-" + months[month] + "<br/>");
  for (let i = startDay; i <= endDay; i++) {
    document.write("<span>" + i + "</span>");
  }
}
for (let year = 2010; year <= 2019; year++) {
  for (let month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
    const startDate = new Date(year, month - 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0)
    const endDate = new Date(year, month, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0); // next month -1 day
    writeMonth(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate(), endDate.getDate())
  }
}
```

```css
span::before {
  content: "|"
}
```